# SConscript EnvironmentError: No module named compilation_db

Tags: scons

I'm trying to compile the GitHub project:  https://github.com/commaai/openpilot, I'm getting an error when creating the SCons environment (the call to Environment()), it points this line :

```
Environement(
# Other options ...
tools=["default", "cython", "compilation_db"
)
```

The result of the scons is then :

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
EnvironmentError: No module named compilation_db:
  File "/home/skoumad/openpilot/master/SConstruct", line 213:
    "compilation_db"
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Environment.py", line 982:
    apply_tools(self, tools, toolpath)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Environment.py", line 107:
    env.Tool(tool)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Environment.py", line 1788:
    tool = SCons.Tool.Tool(tool, toolpath, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Tool/__init__.py", line 118:
    module = self._tool_module()
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Tool/__init__.py", line 215:
    raise SCons.Errors.EnvironmentError(error_string)
```

I tried to install compilation_db using : https://pypi.org/project/scons-compiledb/0.4.7/
but still the same error :/.

Any idea on how to install this missing module ??

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely have a version of SCons older than 4.0.0

The `compilation_db` tool was added in 4.0.0

See [release notice](https://scons.org/scons-400-is-available.html)

If you're distro(linux,python, macports, etc) doesn't have 4.0.0 or newer, then I'd advise setting up a python [virtualenv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) (no this is not a VM, it's just a tool to create a clean python environment to install packages in)

Here's how to do that:

```
# assuming posix system, for win32, of course change the path to windows correct syntax
# also the python below should be 3.5 or newer, generally it's best to use the newest installed
python -m venv ~/sconsvenv 
. ~/sconsvenv/bin/activate
pip install  scons

scons --version

# should yield

SCons by Steven Knight et al.:
    SCons: v4.1.0.post1.dc58c175da659d6c0bb3e049ba56fb42e77546cd, 2021-01-20 04:32:28, by bdbaddog on ProDog2020
    SCons path: ['/Users/bdbaddog/sconsvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/SCons']
Copyright (c) 2001 - 2021 The SCons Foundation
```

Comment: Hi, thanks and yes you're right I have an old version (3.0.1), I used apt get install and it tells that it's the latest version (scons is already the newest version (3.0.1-2).
), I'll try to do apt get update.

Comment: You likely won't get a newer version from your distro.. I'll add info above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the appreciated effort ^^.
Using virtualenv I got : 
Successfully installed scons-4.1.0.post1
But when trying to scons --version it's still the old one :


$ scons --version
SCons by Steven Knight et al.:
        script: v3.0.1.74b

Comment: Reinstalling it using apt-get autoremove and then apt get install scons somehow fixed the issue, I can see that now the scons binary is called from the myenv ^^. Thanks a lot for the great support =)

Comment: You need to activate the virtualenv to get the newly installed scons in your path. Otherwise you'll pick up SCons from your system install (and PATH). Or you can explicitly run scons from ~/sconsvenv/bin/scons

Comment: my scons version is 4.4.0 and I still get this error. what  should I do?

Comment: @user1723583 which platform, which version of python, what are you trying to build? (your own SCons logic, or that from a project you downloaded?) Probably better for you to ask a new question on SO, or bring the question to the scons users group or discord server.